# How to add custom option type image to the cart item in order review page using observer?

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, custom-options

I want to add custom option type as image to quoteitem in checkout review page using observer which observer event is controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index and it fires when goes to checkout page.

In event call in config.xml

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
<observers>
<hackathon_presentation>
<type>singleton</type>
<class>modulename/observer</class>
<method>salesCollectBefore</method>
</hackathon_presentation>
</observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
```

and then in my Observer.php

```
public function salesCollectBefore($observer)
    {    
    $quote_items = $quote->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($quote_items as $item) {
        $customisation['upload_logo'] = "test.png";
            $additionalOptions = array(
                array(
                    'code'  => 'my_code',
                    'label' => 'Logo',
                    'print_value' =>  '<a href="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$customisation['upload_logo'].'">'logo'</a>',
                    'option_value' => '<a href="test">'.$customisation['upload_logo'].'</a>',
                    'value' => $customisation['upload_logo'].
                )
            );
            $item->addOption(
                array(
                     'code'  => 'additional_options',
                     'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),

                )
            );
        }
    }
```

It does not allow me to show as a link to download the image, It shows only the image name . I want to add the image link in order review page and it should be downlodable from the link. How can I achieve this. Can anyone help here? Plz...

Comment: how does the template work?

Comment: There is no custom template for module. Default magento template works here.

Answer (score 2):

`controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` event does `not given` the `Current Quote object` as it `params`.

If want current quite on this event this ,you need to call

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
```

Or

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()
```

**Code:**

```
public function salesCollectBefore($observer)
    { 
    /* add this */   
    $quote=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getQuote()
    $quote_items = $quote->getItemsCollection();
.....
```

So,you cannot get Currentquote object from $observer.As per as magento `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index`  event current.

from this event you can only get onepageController   object

```
   Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName(),
            array('controller_action' => $this));
```